# Dynamic dependency lib/tls search path

Tags: c++, boost, linker, glibc, ldd

I have an executable which depends on two basic boost libraries, `libboost_system` and `libboost_thread`, and when the executable is loading the libraries, the search path bafflingly differs with respect to `lib/tls`:

```
 $ LD_DEBUG=libs ./var.exe
 25130:     find library=libboost_system.so.1.55.0 [0]; searching
 25130:      search path=/opt/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/tls/x86_64:/opt/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/tls:/opt/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/x86_64:/opt/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib         (RPATH from file ./var.exe)
 25130:       trying file=/opt/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/tls/x86_64/libboost_system.so.1.55.0
 25130:       trying file=/opt/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/tls/libboost_system.so.1.55.0
 25130:       trying file=/opt/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/x86_64/libboost_system.so.1.55.0
 25130:       trying file=/opt/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/libboost_system.so.1.55.0
 25130:
 25130:     find library=libboost_thread.so.1.55.0 [0]; searching
 25130:      search path=/opt/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib            (RPATH from file ./var.exe)
 25130:       trying file=/opt/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.55.0
```

The executable has been linked with exactly the same `-rpath=/opt/...` setting for both libraries, and I know that boost have been built by a common invocation of `b2` (ie exactly the same command line parameters for both). The `/etc/ld.so.cache` doesn't have any related entries.

Further, it doesn't seem that there is anything remarkable about the built libraries themselves in terms of rpath or ABI requirements,

```
$ readelf -d /opt/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/libboost_system.so.1.55.0 | grep -i rpath
# empty
$ eu-readelf -h /opt/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/libboost_system.so.1.55.0
# there is no difference in ABI versions
```

Both libraries have exactly the same shared library dependencies, apart from the fact that `libboost_thread` depends on `libboost_system`, and both need GLIBC_2.2.5.

I reckon that it is decided that `libboost_system` somehow needs to links with an **[NPTL](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/nptl-design.pdf)** glibc and that's why `<rpath>/lib/tls` is searched, but it isn't obvious to me looking at the objdump of the `libboost_system` library why it is the case.

**How is an NPTL library is tagged? How does dlopen(3) decide to look in the lib/tls path?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the search path bafflingly differs with respect to lib/tls

You are barking up the wrong tree.

The GLIBC loader takes `RPATH` from your executable, and appends `PLATFORM` strings (`tls/x86_64:tls:x86_64` here) to it to construct the full search path.

Once the loader discovers that e.g. `RPATH/tls` directory does not exist, it removes that entry from the search path (there is no point in repeatedly searching non-existent directory). Eventually you end up with just `RPATH` itself being present.

If you relink your binary to e.g. invert the order of dependency on `libboost_thread` and `libboost_system`, you'll discover that again only the first library is being searched in `RPATH/tls`, etc. and the second only in `RPATH`.